# Need some help for a Query Optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query but it seems to take more than one minute to render a result. Can anyone help me optimize the results? I believe the 2nd query below would help with the first line but not sure how to group

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(delivery_id)
   FROM DeliveryTons
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT BSI_CODE
        FROM FarmerGroups
        WHERE ASSN = 'BSICGP'
          AND BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi
          AND remarks = ''
          AND DeliveryTons.crop_season = 3)) AS Tickets,

  (SELECT COUNT(delivery_id)
   FROM DeliveryTons
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT BSI_CODE
        FROM FarmerGroups
        WHERE ASSN = 'BSICGP'
          AND BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi
          AND DeliveryTons.crop_season = 3)) AS Deliveries,

  (SELECT SUM(tonnage_adjusted)
   FROM DeliveryTons
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT BSI_CODE
        FROM FarmerGroups
        WHERE ASSN = 'BSICGP'
          AND BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi
          AND delivery_status != 'C'
          AND DeliveryTons.crop_season = 3)) AS TonsDelivered,

  (SELECT SUM(tonnage_adjusted)
   FROM DeliveryTons
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT BSI_CODE
        FROM FarmerGroups
        WHERE ASSN = 'BSICGP'
          AND BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi
          AND remarks = ''
          AND DeliveryTons.crop_season = 3)) AS TonsMonitored,

  (SELECT SUM(ACREAGE)
   FROM CaneParcel
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT DISTINCT(parcel_id)
        FROM DeliveryTons
        WHERE EXISTS
            (SELECT BSI_CODE
             FROM FarmerGroups
             WHERE ASSN = 'BSICGP'
               AND BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi
               AND CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = DeliveryTons.parcel_id
               AND DeliveryTons.crop_season = 3))) AS AcresMonitored,

  (SELECT SUM(ACREAGE)
   FROM CaneParcel
   WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT DISTINCT(parcel_id)
        FROM DeliveryTons
        WHERE EXISTS
            (SELECT BSI_CODE
             FROM FarmerGroups
             WHERE ASSN = 'BSICGP'
               AND BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi
               AND remarks = ''
               AND CaneParcel.FIELD_ID = DeliveryTons.parcel_id
               AND parcel_status = '3'
               AND DeliveryTons.crop_season = 3))) AS ClosedAcres



SELECT COUNT(d.delivery_id),
FROM DeliveryTons d
INNER JOIN FarmerGroups F ON F.BSI_CODE = d.farmer_pay_bsi
WHERE t.assn = 'BSICGP'
  AND crop_season = 3
  AND remarks=''
GROUP BY d.delivery_id
```

Here is my DeliveryTons Table:

```
id      crop_season  delivery_id  parcel_id    reaping_code   farmer_owner_name   farmer_owner_bsi   farmer_pay_bsi   tonnage_adjusted   parcel_status   remarks    delivery_status
77701   1             1           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            15.3625            2                          P
77702   1             2           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            17.4625            2                          P
77703   1             3           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            13.5875            2                          P
77704   1             4           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            19.0250            2                          P
77705   1             5           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            19.6375            2                          P
77706   1             6           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            16.2125            2                          P
77707   1             7           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            22.5375            2                          P
77708   1             8           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            18.1000            2                          P
77709   1             9           038 - 0358   CGP001         Not defined         0                   2064            23.0000            2                          P
77710   1            11           016 - 0482   BSFA156        CANUL, MARTIN       844                 7866            19.3000            1                          P
77711   1            12           016 - 0096   BSFA153        ALDANA, MARCOS      986                10024            15.2625            1                          P
77712   1            13           004 - 0684   BSFA155        QUEME, BENANCIO     778                10063            17.8125            1                          P
77713   1            14           004 - 0224   BSFA162        CHABLE, MARCELINO   198                  198            20.5125            1                          P
77714   1            15                        BSFA160                            0                    212            16.0375            0               NO_TICKET  P
77715   1            16                        BSFA159                            0                   4570            12.3875            0               NO_TICKET  P
77716   1            17           016 - 2473   BSFA151                            0                   9173            13.6875            3                          P
77717   1            18           016 - 1566   BSFA149        Not defined         0                   1094            15.7250            1                          P
77718   1            19                        BSFA160                            0                    148            20.2125            0               NO_TICKET  P
77719   1            20           016 - 1566   BSFA149        Not defined         0                   1094            12.7625            2                          P
77720   1            21           016 - 1566   BSFA149        Not defined         0                   1094            15.3875            2                          P
77721   1            22           016 - 2152   BSFA175                            0                    926            15.2625            3                          P
77722   1            23                        BSFA175                            0                   5498            13.7250            0               NO_TICKET  P
```

Cane Parcel Table:

```
geoid   FIELD_ID      BSI_CODE   ACREAGE     ASSN
0       004 - 0567    47          7.359515   CSCPA
1       004 - 0008    281        12.38654    CSCPA
2       004 - 0012    281         7.899037   CSCPA
3       004 - 0013    281         4.937749   CSCPA
4       004 - 0014    281         5.002847   CSCPA
5       004 - 0038    9050        6.731369   CSCPA
6       004 - 0045    9028        4.120158   CSCPA
7       004 - 0039    9050        8.519387   CSCPA
8       004 - 0147    289        14.801      BSCFA - CZ
9       004 - 0572    47          5.878942   CSCPA
10      004 - 0030    281        14.33925    CSCPA
11      004 - 1150    281         7.306061   CSCPA
12      004 - 1152    281         3.814288   CSCPA
13      004 - 0017    281        11.5479     CSCPA
```

FarmerGroups Table:

```
ID      ASSN          BSI_CODE FARMER                       CROP_SEASON
10473   BSCFA - OW    5752       GARCIA,EUGENIO R           2
10474   BSCFA - OW    8894       GARCIA,RAUL R              2
10475   BSCFA - OW    4427       PECH,EVELIA                2
10476   BSCFA - OW    5226       GONZALEZ,DALIA MARIA       2
10477   BSCFA - OW    5753       GONZALEZ,ELVIRA            2
10478   BSCFA - OW    9295       GONZALEZ,RAUL              2
10479   BSCFA - OW    9996       GONZALEZ,TRANSITO          2
10480   BSCFA - OW    10099      PERAZA,ALBERTA             2
10481   BSCFA - OW    4537       GARCIA,SANTIAGO SILVERIO   2
10482   BSCFA - OW    8573       ACK,AMELITA M              2
10483   BSCFA - OW    7467       ACK,EUCARIO                2
10484   BSCFA - OW    7468       ACK,MOISES                 2
10485   BSCFA - OW    1848       AGUIRRE,NENCIE             2
10486   BSCFA - OW    4355       BLANCO,SILVIO              2
10487   BSCFA - OW    4476       CAL,ALBERTA GARCIA         2
10488   BSCFA - OW    4480       CAL,ENRIQUE                2
10489   BSCFA - OW    2545       CAL,ERNESTO T              2
10490   BSCFA - OW    6877       CAL,REMIGIO                2
```

Comment: What database is this for? Oracle? SQL Server? DB2? Firebase? MySQL version 8? MySQL before V8? **These things really matter!** please mention the version along with choosing the correct dbms tag.

Comment: Counting `d.delivery_id` and then `GROUP BY d.delivery_id` really does not make much sense. **Do you expect just a single row in your result?**

Comment: YEs just a single row count result. this is for Microsoft SQL 2008

Comment: if you only want a single row then do not `group by` at all

Comment: To help further really need **sample data** (per table and not images). I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If i remove group by i get 60 rows total which is the answer i need and if i remove the group by the count is 167 which is wrong count.

Comment: That comment does not make sense,  if you DO NOT remove the group by you get 60?? If that is true I suggest you need to use `count (distinct ...)` instead and DO remove the group by.

Comment: The DISTINCT Seems to work for the first 2 lines but how do i make it work for the last 4 lines where its doing SUM

Comment: I added sample data tables with values

Comment: I see some data, but none of it seems to relate directly to your query, e.g. `remarks = '' `or `ASSN = 'BSICGP'` or `BSI_CODE = DeliveryTons.farmer_pay_bsi` **plus** there is no **expected result** (which should be derived from the sample data) so there is nothing to test any query against.  Have a look at this: https://rextester.com/AOV86599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that the FarmerGroups CAN create multiple rows for a single BSI_CODE record, pre-aggregate flags of the farmers groups table ONCE per BSI_CODE. THEN you can sum it without creating a false Cartesian result...

Think of the inner "PQ" (PreQuery) as doing a binary OR between rows.  All you care about is for any single BSI_CODE, does it exist, does it have an empty status (or not), and its delivery status. So, given the sample data of...

```
FarmerGroups
BSI_CODE   Assn     Remarks   Delivery_Status
A          BSICGP   test      B
A          BSICGP             C
A          BSICGP   test      C
A          BSICGP             A
---------------------------------
B          BSICGP   test      B
B          BSICGP   test      C
---------------------------------
C          BSICGP   test      B
---------------------------------
D          BSICGP             
D          BSICGP             X
---------------------------------
E          BSICGP   test1     C
E          BSICGP   test2     C
---------------------------------
```

Now, the summary of each BSI_CODE would result as

```
BSI_CODE   NoRemarks  IsTonDelivery
A          1          1    (at least 1 record had no remarks, at least 1 record was NOT 'C' status)
B          0          1    (NO records had empty remarks, at least 1 was NOT 'C' status)
C          0          1    (only 1 record.  It had a remark, but as NOT 'C' status)
D          1          1    (both no remarks, neither was 'C' status)
E          0          0    (both HAD remarks and BOTH were 'C' status).
```

So you can see 11 records from farmers group is summarized into 5 rows with respective "flag" columns of 1 or 0.

In a somewhat similar approach for your "CaneParcel", pre-sum the acreage based on the field ID so this too gets a single row per field, to be LEFT-JOINED to the delivery tons... The JOIN to the FarmerGroups will pre-qualify that part by transitive condition.

Now, if your DeliveryTons table has 5 records for "D" either summing, counting, or multiplying by the flag will result in 0 or the value trying to get the aggregate of.  You can join to your DeliveryTons table, and since each of your subqueries were relying on the Crop_Season = 3, you can just apply that to your outer query but pulling the above query within...

```
select
        count(*) as Deliveries,
        sum( case when dt.remarks = '' then 1 else 0 end ) as Tickets,
        sum( dt.Tonnage_Adjusted 
            * case when dt.delivery_status != 'C' then 1 else 0 end  ) as TonsDelivered,
        sum( dt.Tonnage_Adjusted 
            * case when dt.remarks = '' then 1 else 0 end ) as TonsMonitored,
        sum( PQ2.totalAcreage ) AcresMonitored,
        sum( case when dt.parcel_status = '3' then cp.Acreage else 0 end
            * case when dt.remarks = '' then 1 else 0 end ) TotalClosedAcres
    from
        DeliveryTons dt
            JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT
                    BSI_CODE,
                FROM 
                    FarmerGroups fg
                WHERE
                    ASSN = 'BSICGP' ) PQ
                ON dt.farmer_pay_bsi = PQ.BSI_CODE

            LEFT JOIN
            (select
                    cp.Field_ID,
                    sum( cp.Acreage ) totalAcreage
                from
                    CaneParcel cp
                group by
                    cp.Field_ID ) PQ2
                on dt.parcel_id = PQ2.Field_ID

    where
        dt.Crop_Season = 3
```

This may be a lot to digest, but do believe (without seeing your actual production data -- or even sample data) will work for you as two quick Pre-Query aggregates (PQ and PQ2) once and directly joined (left join) to the DeliveryTons table.  I would try it in pieces just to see / confirm what is going on.

**UPDATE PER COMMENT**

Updated query.  Without your sample data, my query was written with implied format / content.  After seeing your data, notice there is no value in the farmerGroups table for comments and its in your tonnage table.  Adjusted query to accommodate.

Comment: I am getting these errors : Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'remarks'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'delivery_status'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Invalid column name 'parcel_status'.

Comment: I also uploaded sample data and tables.

Comment: Any reason why i would get these errors. -  Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
Invalid column name 'remarks'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Invalid column name 'delivery_status'.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
The multi-part identifier "dt.parcel_status" could not be bound.

Comment: @ivias, see revision and comment at bottom.

Comment: Okay, I see you have modified but still getting these errors when i try to execute the query.Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'delivery_status'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Invalid column name 'parcel_status'.

Comment: @ivias, one more try... adjusted query.  Same issue.  Did not look at all the other fields.  Let me know if this runs too.

Comment: I fixed Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. but now getting : Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "cp.Acreage" could not be bound.

Comment: **I changed :**  sum( case when dt.parcel_status = '3' then cp.Acreage else 0 end
            * case when dt.remarks = '' then 1 else 0 end ) TotalClosedAcres                                      **to:**  sum( case when dt.parcel_status = '3' then 1  else 0 end
            * case when dt.remarks = '' then 1 else 0 end ) TotalClosedAcres but getting a 1 now for **TotalClosedAcres** @DRapp

Comment: the first 4 lines in my query match yours but the last 2 lines dont not show the same results. @DRapp

Comment: I think your last line in your select statement should be this:    **sum( PQ2.totalAcreage * case when dt.parcel_status = '3' then 1 else 0 end * case when dt.remarks = '' then 1 else 0 end ) TotalClosedAcres**@DRapp

Comment: @ivias, correct... the baseline field you are trying to aggregate TIMES the 1 or 0 based on the flag setting... Glad you are seeing how the purpose is intended vs just GIVING the answer.  I should have caught it, but glad you are following it.  Did you adjust for the "TotalAcreage *  case/end" and is it now working?